# Python build always reinstall setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I am using Python 3.8 in conda, and using build to create packages. Although in my Conda env I already have setuptools 51.0 and wheel 0.36, everytime I run `python -m build --wheel` I see the following messages:

```
Found existing installation: setuptools 49.2.1
Uninstalling setuptools-49.2.1:
  Successfully uninstalled setuptools-49.2.1
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting setuptools>=51
  Using cached setuptools-58.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-58.3.0 wheel-0.37.0
```

Here the existing packages don't even match what I have in Conda, and I don't think I need the newest packages either. Could anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: `build` uses new clean virtualenvs for each build. Why do you think you don't need the newest `setuptools`?

Comment: No specific reasons, just felt the existing packages are fine. So is it normal that build will install the newest packages in a new venv each time? It just seemed a little repetitive to do this each time.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. `build` does that to try to ensure everything builds as cleanly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to this topic https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#python--m-build-optional-arguments

> By default build will build the package **in an isolated environment**, but this behavior can be disabled with `--no-isolation`.

so you may need to add `--no-isolation` flag to force using your project's virtual environment like so:

```
python -m build --wheel --no-isolation
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.